# Проблемы с отправкой картинки с node.js на сервер Flask

Tags: node.js, flask, fetch, formdata, fs

Всем привет! Перепробовал кучу способов отправки картинки, но либо она не приходит, либо постоянно вылазят ошибки. Я с помощью модуля `fs` подгружаю картинку и отправляю запрос на сервер:

```
const imageStream = fs.createReadStream("C:\\Users\\Kvanzi\\Desktop\\images\\image.png");
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", imageStream, "image.png");
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_image", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  })
```

В этом случае на сервер ничего не приходит. Так же пробовал так:

```
const formData = new FormData();
const imageStream = fs.createReadStream("C:\\Users\\Kvanzi\\Desktop\\sendEase\\images\\image.png");
formData.append("file", imageStream, "image.png");
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/send_message", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  })
```

В этом случае вылазит такая ошибка:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.
```

Вот функция сервера Flask, которая принимает файлы:

```
@app.route('/get_image', methods=['POST'])
def get_message():
    request_data = request.form
    files = request.files
```